# Fix HTML5 validator error “Bad value X-UA-Compatible..."

Tags: python, html, validation, plone, meta-tags

I have a web portal in Zope/Plone, and ALL must validate (client requirements). I'm using HTML5. In production, IE "thinks" the Portal is an intranet, so, it forces the compatibility mode.

For fixing this, I have set the typical tag in header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But the W3C validator don't like it:

> “Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.”

There are several fixes for this, as I can see in [JoshuaWinn](http://www.joshuawinn.com/fix-html5-validator-error-bad-value-x-ua-compatible-for-attribute-http-equiv-on-element-meta/). But nothing of these applies to Python or Zope/Plone. Is there any way to set the tag in that CMS?

If validator is correct, as I read [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198594/bad-value-x-ua-compatible-for-attribute-http-equiv-on-element-meta?rq=1)... how can I force the standard mode in IE8?

Comment: So you want to set a HTTP header on every HTML request?

Comment: I supposed so. Well, my goal is that IE don't enter in Quirks mode, and that's the only solution I can think of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the header from the main template; add the following tag to your `main_template.pt` file to have it include the header on every request that uses the main template:

```xml
<tal:add_x_ua_compatible_header define="dummyresult python:request.response.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge,chrome=1')" />
```

Comment: We're unable to test until the project be in production, because in test-enviroment IE still recognising the portal as "intranet", and so, we can't see if it's working. Otherwise, I accept your A, I think this is the proper way, thanks.

Comment: You can verify the headers the server returns, of course. :-)

Comment: Ah? I tried that, but the header returns other META, but no that one. I think that META would be "hidden" or something... to allow the document pass the validation.

Comment: He means the HTTP headers not what's inside <head>. Try ``wget --server-response YOUR_URL``.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. I have check it and yes, now returns the meta (and validate!) Thank you!