# Bad value X-UA-Compatible

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

I am using the validator.w3
I got this kind of error

```
 Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

the header.php says:

```
<?php
    wp_head();
    woo_head();
?>
```

for it to be generated...I would like to ask if what specific point could this woo_head(); located...please help

Comment: `woo_head()` is custom method defined by `woo themes`. And to get the exact value you have to find the defined value in the whole theme, better way is contact them to get support related to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this because `X-UA-Compatible` is not a valid value for `http-equiv` on the `meta` tag, **according to the W3C Validator**.

The `X-` prefix denotes a vendor specific custom extension, just like a `data-` attribute.  So, in summary, although this makes sense, the *standard* dictates it is wrong, so the validator itself is correct.  You can read the [full W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv), which contains a list of the expected values for `http-equiv`.

As for where this is coming from, it's likely in your `header.php` file of your theme, probably the first line.

The `woo_head()` method itself is part of WooThemes, and their framework.

Comment: As a matter of fact that thread isn't quite complete. The `http-equiv` meta tag should, by its very definition, accept any valid HTTP header. The `X-` prefix denotes a 'vendor specific custom' extension, similar to `data-` attributes in HTML5, and should thus be allowed by all means. So the precise status is that the validator is 'correct' to reject it because the *standard* it's following is bugged.

Comment: Thanks.  I've changed the answer to better reflect this.

Comment: "The http-equiv tag should accept any valid HTTP header" — No, it shouldn't. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv

Comment: The situation (the validator) has changed now, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108614/why-does-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-chrome-1-is-not-validate

Answer (score 0):

Please read this post for more info : [Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198594/bad-value-x-ua-compatible-for-attribute-http-equiv-on-element-meta)

The fix that I recommend is :

```
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
```

You will find the code in your wordpress theme folder : wp-contents/themes/your-theme/header.php

Comment: I cant find the line in header.php I think it is generated by a function.. what Line should I specifically locate it,if it could be found at header.php? this is the first line for my header.php
<head>



<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />



<title><?php woo_title(); ?></title>

<?//php woo_meta(); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" media="screen" />

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<?php

 wp_head();

 woo_head();

?>

</head>

Comment: I appears that you are using a custom woo theme. I could not tell you where the theme headers are located. If you have shell access, you can try a text search : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux/16957078#16957078