# Why does http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" is not validated in W3C Validator?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, w3c-validation, x-ua-compatible

I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

On validation in http://validator.w3.org/ I get this error:

> A meta element with an http-equiv attribute whose value is
>   X-UA-Compatible must have a content attribute with the value IE=edge.

I am working with **.NET/Razor** and of course locally using **IIS**. Is there a way to solve this without editing any *web.config* files? 
Thanks in forward.

Comment: Why you want to add `chrome=1` to the `content`?

Answer (score 12):

According to [this](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2011Mar/0053.html) discussion in the W3C, using the `chrome=1` part is not allowed.

You can pass the validation by using just like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```